# Como regresar la collection de Items a combobox en c#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, combobox

Buen dia,
Tengo un combobox que cargo con un dato mediante un query desde un boton (Buscar), ese mismo combobox tiene una collection de datos(15 items desde las propiedades) cuando abro el formulario la primera vez, pero despues de cargarlo desde la base de datos, despues de limpiarlo ya no me aparece la collection de datos, solo me aparece en la collection el dato que carge de la base de datos.
Lo limpio asi:

```
cmb.SelectedIndex = -1
```

Esto si limpia mi combobox pero yo quiero que me regrese la collection completa como cuando lo ejecuto la primera vez.
Quisera hacer como un refresh o algo que me recargue el combobox como el princio...
Como se le haria en ese caso?

Información adicional:
Asi es como cargo el combobox:

```
SqlCommand micommand= new SqlCommand(querySQL,conexion);

        SqlDataReader BuscaRead;
        conexion.Open();
        BuscaRead = micommand.ExecuteReader();
       //si trae datos los consulta le paso el dato al combo directamente, no utilizo datasource ya que solo devuelbe un dato
        if (BuscaRead.Read())
        {
combo.Items.Add(BuscaRead["campo"].ToString());
        }
```

Cuando le paso el dato al combobox y despues uso un boton llamado "cancelar" que limpia otros campos y quiero tambien que se limpie el combo y regrese la lista que yo le asigne desde propiedades, pero no regresa esa lista, solo aparece el campo que se le agrego desde la base de datos. Como se le puede regresar la collection de datos que tenia desde el principio?

Comment: esta un poco confuso lo que planteas, partamos de la base que SelectedIndex = -1 no limpia nada, solo cambias el item seleccionado pero si desplegas deberias seguir viendo la lista. Como es que asignas los items usas el DataSource o el Items.Add() ?

Comment: Solo le asigno un valor el combobox y utilizo datareader combo.Items.Add(BuscaRead["campo"].ToString());  y la idea de utilizar SelectdIndex = -1 es exactamente como lo comentas cambiar el item seleccionado solo que no lo puede explicarlo, entonces como le regreso la lista que yo le configure desde propiedades?

Comment: como le asignas ese valor ? usas el SelectedValue, como utilizas el datareader ? lo asignas al DataSource

Comment: asi asigno el dato al combo:

    SqlCommand micommand= new SqlCommand(querySQL,conexion);
            
            SqlDataReader BuscaRead;
            conexion.Open();  
            BuscaRead = micommand.ExecuteReader();
           //si trae datos la consulta le paso el dato al combo directamente, no utilizo datasource ya que solo devuelbe un dato
            if (BuscaRead.Read())
            {
 combo.Items.Add(BuscaRead["campo"].ToString());
            }
es lo mismo que mencione antes.

Comment: porque no editas la pregunta y pones el codigo con mejor formato

Comment: @LeandroTuttini pregunta editada...

Answer (score 0):

Para asignar datos al combo usa una entidad y no el Items.Add(), como ser

```
conexion.Open();
SqlCommand micommand= new SqlCommand(querySQL,conexion);

SqlDataReader BuscaRead = micommand.ExecuteReader();

List<Item> lista = new List<Item>();
if (BuscaRead.Read())
{
    var item = new Item() 
    { 
        campo = Cnvert.ToString(BuscaRead["campo"])
    };

    lista.Add(item);
}

combo.ValueMember = "campo";
combo.DisplayMember = "campo";
combo.DataSource = lista;
```

Para esto define una clase

```
public Item{
   public string campo {get;set;}
}
```

en este caso solo indicas un campo, entonces en el codigo podras hacer

```
combo.SelectedValue = val;
```

donde "val" es un valor que existe en campo

Comment: Funciona para agregar items al combobox, pero el punto es como le regreso la lista (collection) que yo le asigne desde propiedades al combo despues de que yo le de "cancelar busqueda" o "limpiar" desde un boton?